# Get data to database and re-insert if has match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm making a php search form that the user will type their id and if has match it will re-insert the data to database.

I manage get the data and display the value under my submit button.

My problem now is how to insert data after search. Is it possible to re-insert
the data in same table if has a match?

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" target="_blank" role="button">Time-in<i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-2"></i>
</a>
<?php print $output; ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header blue accent-1">
        <h5 class="modal-title" style="color:white;" id="exampleModalLabel">Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
          <h5>
            <p> Click Continue </p>
          </h5>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="test.html" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right:220px; color:#fff; background:#00bcd4" href="#exampleModal2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2" target="_blank" role="button">Yes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade " id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header blue accent-1">
        <h3 class="mt-2" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Confirm Identity:</h3>
        <a href="sample.php" button type="btn" class="close" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="md-form input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control added-padding-2" placeholder="Search for ID..." name="search" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="11" id="textsend" onKeyUp="success()">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect my-0"  type="submit" href="#exampleModal3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3" target="_blank" role="button" id="button" disabled>Time-in</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $sql =  "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM test WHERE id LIKE '$searchq'" ;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 0){
          $output ='No results!'; 
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
          $fname = $row['fname'];
          $lname = $row['lname'];
          $id = $row['id'];
          $output .= '<div>'.$fname.''.$lname.'</div>';

        }
      }
    }  
?>
```

```js
function success() {
    if(document.getElementById("textsend").value==="") { 
        document.getElementById('button').disabled = true; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
    }
}

function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Database:

[image]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: "will re-insert the data to database"...to where? The same table? Another table? What should be re-inserted - the whole record, or just something to say the record ID was matched? It seems strange to duplicate your data like this. What's the reason for doing so? But yes you can simply run another query (or queries) directly in your PHP to do that task, using the results of the search query.

Comment: re insert same table , its for attendance , i have column name number as primary key and auto increment

Comment: "for attendance"? Not sure I understand. Wouldn't it be better to _update_ the same record and a set a field, rather than re-inserting the whole record again (and thus duplicating the data)? Or have a sub-table which records multiple "attendance" records for that person, so you can view attendance as it changes over time? You haven't made the requirement very clear so I'm just speculating. But as a general rule, making copies of your data is not a good idea. The whole point of a relational database is to make sure no data is repeated or redundant.

Comment: my original idea was the user will type their id and if has match after sumit the value will be display on modal my modal has firstname lastname textbox and a datepicker inside its like for update , but no one answer's my question when i posted it so i came up of idea of re insert the data

Comment: " the user will type their id and if has match after sumit the value will be display on modal"...that requirement has nothing to do with re-inserting your data into the database. You don't need to do that in order to display in a modal. To display in a modal you just need to write a little bit of HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the Insert query at the end of else loop, as below and try:

```
<?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $searchq = $_POST['search'];
      $sql =  "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM test WHERE id LIKE '$searchq'" ;
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if ($count == 0) {
        $output ='No results!'; 
      } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $fname = $row['fname'];
          $lname = $row['lname'];
          $id = $row['id'];
          $output .= '<div>'.$fname.''.$lname.'</div>';
          $InsertSql = "INSERT INTO test(fname,lname,id) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$id')";
          $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql);
        }
      }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: technically this is potentially correct but did you stop to ask yourself whether blindly duplicating the data is actually a _good idea_? Why, in a correct relational database design, would anyone want or need to do such a thing? It's not logical. Sometimes it's better to challenge the requirement than to simply provide code which enables a bad solution.

Comment: Yes , I agree with you. But this guy is new to programming (as mentioned in his stackoverflow profile) so I just answered his query rather than introducing terms like PDO,Database Design etc which might confuse him. He can learn all that slowly by making mistakes at the initial stage.

Comment: We could speed up the learning process by pointing out flaws in the approach, though. In any case, if you read the comments above, you'll see this is actually an X-Y problem - OP had a different requirement originally, didn't find a solution, and has now invented a solution which will not actually solve the original problem, but the question is about a problem with the second solution, even though it won't fix the thing they wanted to do originally. So the whole question is a dead end, essentially.

Comment: @Shivram nadar, thanks it works :) now i will just think how to submit current date after clicking submit button.

Comment: Ohh yes. I just read previous comments. Thanks for correcting me @ADyson. It would have been easier if he had not changed his question.Hope he benefits from your above comments.

Comment: You are Welcome @ace.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
include_once('connection.php');
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $sql =  "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM test WHERE id LIKE '$searchq'" ;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count == 0) {
    $output ='No results!'; 
  } else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $fname = $row['fname'];
      $lname = $row['lname'];
      $id = $row['id'];
      $output .= '<div>'.$fname.''.$lname.'</div>';
      $id1 = $row['id']
      $sql1 = "UPDATE test SET col_name=value WHERE id='$id1'";
      if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql1 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Remove quotation from `$id1` if it's an integer.